# logical error while deleting node from linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to make a method to delete a node from a linked list (could be the first one, a middle one or the last one). Here is the method:

```
public static Node deleteNode(Node head, int value){
    if(head==null){
        return null;
    }else{
        if(head.next==null){ // if there is only one element 
            if(head.value == value){
                head =null; 
            }
        }
        else{                 // if there a more than one elements in the list
            Node t1= head;
            Node t2 = head.next;
            while(t2.next!=null){
                if(t2.value ==value){
                    t1 = t2.next;
                    t2.next=null; 
                    return t2; 
                }
                t2 = t2.next;
                t1 = t1.next; 
            }
            return null; 
        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

To test this method I added some nodes with two methods that I made before and then tell it to find if there's a 9 in the linked list and delete it:

```
    head = addAtTheBeginning(head,3); printLinkedList(head); 
    head = addAtTheBeginning(head,19);printLinkedList(head); 
    head = addAtTheBeginning(head, 4);printLinkedList(head); 
    head = addAtTheBeginning(head, 9);printLinkedList(head); 
    head = addAtTheBeginning(head, 7); printLinkedList(head); 
    head = addAtTheEnd(head, 100); printLinkedList(head); 
    head = addAtTheEnd(head, 200); printLinkedList(head); 
    System.out.println("---"); 
    Node del = deleteNode(head, 9);
    System.out.println(del); 
    System.out.println("---"); 
    del.printNode();
    printLinkedList(head);
```

It prints out this:

```
[3]->]
[19]->[3]->]
[4]->[19]->[3]->]
[9]->[4]->[19]->[3]->]
[7]->[9]->[4]->[19]->[3]->]
[7]->[9]->[4]->[19]->[3]->[100]->]
[7]->[9]->[4]->[19]->[3]->[100]->[200]->]
---
[9]->
---
[9]->[7]->[9]->]
```

I believe that there is a logical error in my code, but I just can't find it .

Here's the complete code so you can make sense of it better.

```
class Node{
    public int value; 
    public Node next;

    public Node (int value){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null; 
    }

    public void printNode(){
        System.out.print( this.toString() ); 
    }

    public String toString(){
        return new String("["+value+"]->");
    }


}

public class m14_06{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node head = null; 

        head = addAtTheBeginning(head,3); printLinkedList(head); 
        head = addAtTheBeginning(head,19);printLinkedList(head); 
        head = addAtTheBeginning(head, 4);printLinkedList(head); 
        head = addAtTheBeginning(head, 9);printLinkedList(head); 
        head = addAtTheBeginning(head, 7); printLinkedList(head); 
        head = addAtTheEnd(head, 100); printLinkedList(head); 
        head = addAtTheEnd(head, 200); printLinkedList(head); 
        System.out.println("---"); 
        Node del = deleteNode(head, 9);
        System.out.println(del); 
        System.out.println("---"); 
        del.printNode();
        printLinkedList(head); 

    }


    public static Node deleteNode(Node head, int value){
        if(head==null){
            return null;
        }else{
            if(head.next==null){ // if there is only one element 
                if(head.value == value){
                    head =null; 
                }
            }
            else{                 // if there a more than one elements in the list
                Node t1= head;
                Node t2 = head.next;
                while(t2.next!=null){
                    if(t2.value ==value){
                        t1 = t2.next;
                        t2.next=null; 
                        return t2; 
                    }
                    t2 = t2.next;
                    t1 = t1.next; 
                }
                return null; 
            }
        }
        return null; 
    }

    /*
    * returns the number of Node in the linked list. 
    */
    public static int countElements(Node head){
        int count = 0; 
        Node t = head;
        while(t!=null){ // while t does point to a node. 
            count++;   // count the node
            t=t.next;  // move to the next

        }
        return count; 
    }

    public static Node search(Node head, int value){
        Node p = head;
        while(p!=null){
            if(p.value==value){
                return p;
            }
            p = p.next; 
        }
        return null; 
    }

    public static void printLinkedList(Node head){
        Node p = head;
        while(p!=null){
            p.printNode();
            p = p.next;
        }
        System.out.println("]"); 
    }

    public static Node addAtTheBeginning(Node head, int value){
        Node temp = new Node(value); 
        if(head==null){
            head = temp ; 
            return head; 
        }else{
            temp.next = head;  // (1) 
            head = temp; 
        }
        return head; 
    }

    public static Node addAtTheEnd(Node head, int value){
        Node temp = new Node(value);
        Node p; 
        if(head == null){
            head = temp;
            return head; 
        }else{
            p = head;
            while(p.next!=null){
                p=p.next;
            }
            p.next = temp; 
            return head; 
        }
    }   
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will remove *all* matching nodes from the input list.  If you want to remove only the *first* matching node, the code below would require a slight refactor.  I have tested this code on IntelliJ and it worked correctly for every use case which came to mind.

```
public static Node deleteNode(Node head, int value) {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }

    while (head.value == value) {
        head = head.next;
        if (head == null) return null;
    }

    Node t1 = head;
    Node t2 = t1.next;

    while (t2 != null) {
        // check for a match
        if (t2.value == value) {
            // splice out node t2
            t1.next = t2.next;
            t2 = t2.next;
        }
        // otherwise advance pointers by one
        else {
            t1 = t2;
            t2 = t2.next;
        }
    }

    return head; 
}
```

Comment: @KyriakosPap I just updated, please reload the page and try again, thanks.

Comment: this gave me the same output as the previous edit:  [7]->[7]->[4]->[19]->[3]->[100]->[200]->]. although it deletes 9, for some reason it shows 7 twice.

Comment: @KyriakosPap I tested this answer fairly thoroughly on IntellIj and it seems to be working.  I think you might have a problem with your data.

Comment: you are probably right but i can't find it. Could it be possible to send the code that you have, cause i think that i deleted something by mistake..(if of course it's different that the one in my question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static Node deleteNode(Node head, int value){
    if(head==null){
        return null;
    }else{
        if(head.next==null){ // if there is only one element 
            if(head.value == value){
                head =null; 
            }
        }
        else{                 // if there a more than one elements in the list
            Node t1= head;
            Node t2 = head.next;
            while(t2.next!=null){
                if(t2.value ==value){
                    t1 = t2.next;
                    t2.next=null; 
                    return t2; 
                }
                t2 = t2.next;
                t1 = t1.next; 
            }
            return null; 
        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Alright, where to start... The return value is completely irrelevant here. You never use it. Even if you did, you almost always return null, except for when you return the node you wanted to remove.

Also, you never remove the node you're searching for. Never.

Let's start with if it's not the head. You will find the node (in your example the 9) and remove everything that follow:

```
if(t2.value ==value){
    t1 = t2.next;
    t2.next=null; 
    return t2; 
}
```

This will remove everything BEHIND the note you wanted to remove (`t2.next=null`).
Also, `t1 = t2.next;` is completely pointless, as you never use t1 again after the return.

```
if(t2.value ==value){
    t1.next = t2.next;
    return; 
}
```

This is more what you need. You need to "skip" t2 by setting the next of t1 to the next of t2. I also removed the unnecessary return type, though that will only work if your method is void.

Okay, next step: What if it's the head?

You will set `head = null;`

Which would be great if it worked, except it won't,  because you will only change the object your parameter points to to null, not what the actual head of your list points to.

Sadly with a static method like this, you won't be able to delete the head at all. You could use a return value to indicate you need to remove the head after the method but that would kind of defeat the purpose.

A better option might be to use a list paremeter instead of a node parameter, so you can change the actual reference of the given list instead of just your local reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead this part

```
if (t2.value == value) { 
t1 = t2.next;
t2.next = null;
return t2;
}
```

to

```
if (t2.value == value) { 
t1.next = t2.next;
return t2;
}
```

then the list will delete [9] like `[7]->[4]->[19]->[3]->[100]->[200]->]`

Comment: Still won't allow him to remove the head though.

Comment: remove the head? which one? After delete [9], the head is still [7], I don't think it should be delete. if you mean the first [9] from last line of output, it's print from `del.printNode();`, not from `printLinkedList(head); `

Comment: No in the example he doesn't remove the head but the method should still be able to do that.

Comment: OK, I noticed it. I think change `head` to instance variable is workable if @Tim wanna do this inside the method, and have to chagne local variables to other name. BTW, It's a bit weird that `head = head.next`. I think head should be unique in a list

Answer (score 0):

I already posted an answer, this one is just to help you understand what went wrong with your code before (I'm gonna pretend the initial list ended with the 3):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In else part where you are checking for more than 1 element in deleteNode, change while condition with this:

```
     while (t2.next != null) {
        if (t2.value == value) {
            t1.next = t2.next;
            t2.next = null;
            return t2;
        }
        t2 = t2.next;
        t1 = t1.next;
     }
```

And also while displaying you arenot giving space between printing deleted node and printing list. Thats why it looks like Node to be deleted got add at begining. Just give println there:

```
del.printNode();
System.out.println("  ");
printLinkedList(head);
```

Hope it helped. :)